# How to pass in runtime a index of row for DataView?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-3.5

I have an question, On my page i have a DataView control, I also have a button that has CommandArgument. I know i can read the DataView as :

```
myDataView.Rows[i].FindControl("FaqQuestion");
```

I want to add index value in runtime to the CommantParameter, so when i go to the Function onCommand i will know exactly from what row[i] i Need to get my controls from DataView.

So my question is, how do i dinamicly add index of DataView.Rows[i] into CommmandArgument for the Button in runtime ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the OnDataBinding event for the button.  In the event, assign the CommandArguemnt value to whatever you want.  Normally you would assign an ID or some other identifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ItemTemplate>
<%# Container.ItemIndex %>
</ItemTemplate>
```